# RTP Streaming in Windows Phone 8?

Tags: windows-phone-8, voip, rtp, codec

I am having the problem in creating rtp streaming in windows phone 8. Is anyone having the sample of RTP streaming and g711 codec in windows phone 8?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

it is not a build in protocol so you will need some addtional libraries.

The best is: http://xmedianet.codeplex.com/

Comment: ya i know this library, but it doesn't completed(partial xmpp jingle only completed). I am looking for Webrtc like library